# How to check what version of flutter sdk xcode is using?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have several versions of the flutter sdk installed on my machine, each has an alias. I'm not sure what version xcode is using when building the app, how can I check it?

UPDATE:
I found a solution, information about flutter sdk which is used to build the version via xcode you can find in `ios/Flutter/Generated.xcconfig`. From here you can change the specific sdk path in `FLUTTER_ROOT`.